# If there exists a nbh $V_0\ni f(x)$, the preimage of any open subset in $V_0$ is a nbh of $x$, then $f$ is continuous at $x$?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X,Y$ be topological space, the map $f:X\to Y$ is continuous at $x\in X$, if for any open neighborhood $V\ni f(x)$, there exists an open subset $x\in U \subset X$, such that $U\subset f^{-1}(V)$.

Since continuous at $x$ is a local property，I wonder whether the above condition can be weakend. i.e. If there exists an open nbh $V_0\ni f(x)$, such that for any $V\subset V_0$, there exists $U$ (depends on V) such that $x\in U\subset f^{-1}(V)$, then we can get that $f$ is continuous at $x$?

If $f:X\to Y$ is a homeomorphism,  then for any open subset  $U\subset X$, is $f(U)$ an open subset of $Y$?

Comment: Are you asking whether the existence of such a $V_0$ is enough to show that $f$ is continuous?

Comment: @G.Chiusole: Yes

Answer (score 2):

For the first question the answer is YES: Just apply the hypothesis to $V \cap V_0$. For the second question use the fact that $f(U)=(f^{-1})^{-1}(U))$.

Comment: $U$ is an open subset of $X$, what's $f^{-1}(U)$?

Comment: @mathmetricgeometry There was a typo.